# MySQL does not divide columns

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working with SQuirreL SQL on a MS SQL Server and using an appropriate `select` statement, I have extracted the following information from a table:

```
date       | case_type | case_model | click | view | display
YYYY-MM-DD | string_A  | string_B   | INT   | INT  | INT
```

where `click`, `view` and `display` have been summed up and `date`, `case_type` and `case_model` have been grouped by.

What I would like to do now is **sum** `click` and `view` and **divide** by `display`, grouped by `date`, `case_type` and `case_model`.

To do this, I first do a sub-select in the following way:

```
select t1.date, 
       t1.case_type, 
       t1.case_model,
       case when t1.date is not null 
            then (t1.click+t1.view)
            else '0'
       end as 'click_n_view',
       t1.display
from  my_original_table as t1
```

This produces a table with the desired output

```
date       | case_type | case_model | click_n_view | display
YYYY-MM-DD | string_A  | string_B   | INT          | INT
```

Now, all I would like to do is **divide** `click_n_view` by `display`. Using the same logic as above, I do another sub-select:

```
select t2.date, t2.case_type, t2.case_model, 
       case when t2.date is not null 
            then (t2.click_n_view/t2.display)
            else '0'
       end as 'lead_rate'
from  t1 as t2
```

However, for some reason the **output stays unchanged** and I still get:

```
date       | case_type | case_model | click_n_view | display
YYYY-MM-DD | string_A  | string_B   | INT          | INT
```

Does anyone know how I can get MySQL to calculate the last operation?

Comment: But what is your query? right now I only see separated querys instead some subquerys.

Comment: When both operands are integers, MySQL will return with an integer. Cast/convert at least one of them or both to decimal or to float (decimal is advised) Ohh and btw, MySQL is not SQL Server. Anyways, this stands for both.

Comment: I can't believe this. You have a column aliased as "lead_rate", it just can't return a column named "display". Also your post is confusing, you begin by stating this is SQL server and you end up with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

This means INT/INT = INT (rounded). If you want something else, convert one of them to a data type which has lower precedence or convert both of them.

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,4), [column]) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,4), [column])
```

Change the decimal size and precision to match to your end result's requirements (and to be able to hold the input values too).

MySQL works similarly, use CAST or CONVERT (consult with the documentation about the usage).

---

Please use the proper tags and don't mix product names in questions.

Comment: I thought to that at first glance but his question is very confusing and finally I  dont think this is the real issue but rather that with the last query he end up with the result of the penultimate query. Anyway if you have correctly decyphered his issue, with MySQL using [DIV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) operator is also an option: `(t2.click_n_view DIV t2.display)`

Comment: @ThomasG Yeah, I know it is not 100% clear in the question, but I am pretty sure that this is the problem (getting 0 as a result or something like this). I am also thinking to click or not click on the close button (typography / not clear).